# Exponentially Delay Client Side API Calls

Tags: c#, vb.net, algorithm, throttling, timedelay

I'm interfacing with a third party API that returns a call limit threshold and how many calls I've used of the threshold so far. I believe it's 60 calls every minute. After 1 minute it resets.

I would like to delay my API calls as I reach that limit more and more, sort of like an exponential curve where the curve hits double the max threshold at the max threshold.

So at 0 it's 0 delay. At 60 it would be a 120 second delay.

And if they change the call limit, I want to be able to respond and adjust my max limit again to 2 * the new limit with an exponential-sorta curve.

What algorithm can I use for this? (Preferable VB.NET, else C#)

Comment: Sleeping for Math.Pow(x,y)-z will give you the exponential delay you need, but I'd have to work out what values you'd need to match the curve you're after...

Comment: Why not `Delay(timeRemaining/callsRemaining)` (in appropriate units) so that remaining calls are evenly spaced?

Comment: @JohnWu because most of the time I will likely not be near the threshold and I don’t want to throttle unnecessarily. But on busy days I end up hitting the API more, as do other apps we have that are all calling the same API. We’re also in talks with the vendor to up our limit.

Comment: What's the point? Aren't you artificially implementing what the API throttling is doing anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially do something along these lines, we did this to not bombard our mail server when a camera went offline or had an error.

```
public static class Delay
{
     public static double ByInterval(int maximum, int interval) => Math.Round((maximum / (Math.Pow(2, interval) - 1)), 0);
}
```

So for instance, if the maximum delay should be one hundred twenty and we'd like at an interval of three, the output would be fifteen.  I'm also rounding to a whole number.  Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but we coupled this to an appender, so we store the emails until our threshold is met.  We used our values to equate into seconds with `(10000000 * Delay.By(120, 3))` for instance.  Since we stored as ticks primarily.

Comment: This looks good and it would probably work. But I just cheaped out on it and coded a few multipliers for a few specific ranges instead. Thank you though!

Comment: @John Yeah, don't blame you.  The odds of encountering are slim, so why over optimize.